# How to disable opening records from Odoo pivot table

Tags: odoo-9

In Odoo pivot view, when clicking on a value in the table, it opens the correspondig record(s) in a tree view. Is it possible to disable reaching the records from this view. If so, how to proceed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. In xml view file

> `<pivot string="Report" disable_linking="True">`